# Proving a point lies between two others

Tags: analytic-geometry

how can I show that the point $Q = (2, 5, -3)$ lies between $P(1, 6, -5)$ and $R(4, 3, 1)$? I have already proved that the three points are collinear, but I would like to show which is in the middle. Is there any way, other than drawing a picture, that can prove this fact?

Comment: In order to get an answer that you can use, you might give us your definition of when a point lies between two others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R$ is a candidate to be between $P$ and $R$.

To check it, using barycentric coordinates, you have to show the system of equations in $t$
$$tP+(1-t)R=Q\iff\begin{cases}t+4(1-t)=2\\6t+3(1-t)=5\\-5t+1-t=-3
\end{cases}$$
has a solution $t\in[0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already established the collinearity of your points, you can just compare the $x$ values.

You have $$1<2<4$$

Thus $Q$ is between $P$ and $R$

Comment: That is 100% true, but I don't think it's necessarily obvious to someone new to 3D geometry.

Comment: It should be easy for the OP who has established the collinearity of three points.

Answer (score 1):

We have that the line PR is given by

$$P+t(R-P)=(1, 6, -5)+t(3, -3, 6)$$

then check whether $\exists t$ such that

$$(2, 5, -3)=(1, 6, -5)+t(3, -3, 6)$$

and recall that

- $t=0$ gives $P$
- $t=1$ gives $R$
- $0<t<1$ the point lies between $P$ and $R$

Comment: This seems like you answered one question, you realized you misread the question, then quickly patched up the answer.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Yes exactly, at first I've misread the OP and then fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first find the line that goes through these three points. The line can be represented as $$(x,y,z)=(1,-1,2)\cdot t + (2,5,-3)$$

So, what values of $t$ produce each one of the points? $t=0$ obviously produces $Q$, $t=-1$ produces $P$ and $t=2$ produces $R$. Since $-1<0<2$, we are done.